# Making photo gallery for OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, software-recommendations, photos

me and my collegue are making a web map application for my town for tourism purpose. The map itself is pretty done, actually, so we were wondering whether add some photos of the town, or that shows photos of the feature that has been selected. Something pretty much like Google Maps.

Is there any plugin that fits correctly with OpenLayers that does this job correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a vectorlayer you can insert an image into your popup for example like this:
http://www.ereca.org.uk/olexamples/PopupPNG.htm

there are existing examples with Flickr-Photos:
http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/georss-flickr.html

and if you want to to use a WMS-Service you could for example use your own Freemarker Template in Geoserver to show the Images in the GetFeatureInfo-Response...

just three examples. there are a lot more possible ways to implement the functionality ;)

and if you don't just want to show "simple" images but a real image gallery you can take something like Lightbox ( http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ ) , Galleria ( http://galleria.io/ ) or any other javascript image gallery and combine it with your select control. ( http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/select-feature.html )
here a screenshot of an ol-app with Galleria-Popups:
[image]